# Malihu Scrollbar in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery');?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/cusscroll/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/cusscroll/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/cusscroll/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/cusscroll/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/cusscroll/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#primary").mCustomScrollbar({
            scrollInertia:900,
           scrollEasing:"easeOutQuint",
            mouseWheel:true
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

That is just part of my header. Im trying to install Malihu scrollbar for the #Primary content box.
No matter how I try it, it is still not working, all I see is the regular scrollbar.

Here is my CSS for the #primary content box just in case:

```
#primary
{
    float:left;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-radius:5px;
    background: none;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:7px;
    margin-left:15px;
    width:650px;
    height:800px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-family:verdana;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Please help! I need to finish this up quick. What am I doing wrong here? Do I have to add any additional codes?

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom javascript, try using `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` as your first line, instead of just `(function($)`

so...

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#primary").mCustomScrollbar({
            scrollInertia:900,
            scrollEasing:"easeOutQuint",
            mouseWheel:true
        });
    });
});
</script>
```